# in one class run many class, PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

i have class "User_registration" and in this class i need use many class: "Location", "Links", "Mail", "Module".

i create include all class in file:
include 'class/location.php';
include 'class/links.php';
include 'class/mail.php';
include 'class/modules.php';

Now create "User_registration" class.

```
<?php
class User_registration{

    public function insert_to_db($name, $country_code, $home_page)
    {
        //work with data

        return id;
    }

    public function show_info($id)
    {
        //work with data
    }

}

$reg_u = new User_registration;
$res = $reg_u->insert_to_db($name, $country_code, $home_page);

if($res){
    $reg_u->show_info($res);
}
?>
```

I need in method "insert_to_db" run class: "Location", "Links", "Mail" methods
and in "show_info" run some methods of "Location", "Links", "Module" class.

How? How in one class run another class (no't one)

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: You can either create an instance of the object and invoke their methods, or if its suitable make the methods static and call them statically.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this.  If you have only a couple objects that another class needs to utilize, use dependency injection; Pass each object as an argument into a class's constructor and store those objects as a class property.

If only a single method needs the object, pass the object as an argument of the method. I discourage this approach though, because I feel it hinders expandability/code-cleanliness in the long run.

If you have many objects that are needed in several classes, I recommend a registry that you inject into a class's constructor.  The registry is a singleton (it holds a single instance of each object you need to share). In the class that needs to utilize a shared object, you might call `$this->registry->get('Some_Shared_Object')->doSomething()`.

---

Dependency Injection (at the constructor)

```
class Foo {
    protected $dependency1;
    protected $dependency2;
    protected $dependency3;

    public function __construct($dependency1, $dependency2, $dependency3) {
        $this->dependency1 = $dependency1;
        $this->dependency2 = $dependency2;
        $this->dependency3 = $dependency3;
    }

    public function foo() {
        $this->dependency1->doSomething();
    }
}

$foo = new Foo($dependency1, $dependency2, $dependency3);
$foo->foo();
```

---

Dependency Injection (at the method, not recommended)

```
class Foo {
    public function foo($dependency1) {
        $dependency1->doSomething();
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->foo($dependency1);
```

---

Dependency Injection using a Registry

```
class Registry {
    var $data = array();

    function __get($key) {
        return $this->get($key);
    }

    function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->set($key, $value);
    }

    /**
    * Retrieve a resource from the registry.
    *
    * @param string
    * @return mixed|null
    */
    function get($key) {
        return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : NULL;
    }

    /**
    * Store a resource in the registry.
    *
    * @param string
    * @param mixed
    */
    function set($key, &$value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
    * Check if a resource exists in the registry.
    *
    * @param string
    * @return boolean
    */
    function has($key) {
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }
}

class Foo {
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function foo() {
        $this->registry->dependency1->doSomething();
    }
}

$dependency1 = new Dependency1();
$registry = new Registry();
$registry->set('dependency1', $dependency1);

$foo = new Foo($registry);
$foo->foo();
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe have some examples?

Answer (score 1):

As good practice I always use an include_once/require_once when I call a class from a class. That way I know no matter where a use a class its references are taken care of and don't over lap.

Well initialize an instance of each and call your methods from there. Don't be afraid of static references.

Comment: Are you talking about including a file (a dependency, e.g. a class) from within a class? If so, that's bad for flexibility.